# How to call a modal window with bootstrap 5 by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In Bootstrap 4 I have done it but due to jquery, in Bootstrap 5 jquery is not available, so how do I call a modal window by javascript without jquery in Bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want like this :

```
// Create your modal
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options);

// Or you can get a modal already present in DOM
var myModalEl = document.getElementById('myModal')
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(myModalEl)

// Open
myModal.show();

// Hide
myModal.hide()
```

For more details, please refer to Bootstrap Documentation :
[Modal via Javascript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript)

Comment: Question: Does it apply to buttons as well?